# Erlang getting error ** 1: syntax error before: '->' **

Tags: erlang

I have started some hands on in Erlang and I am getting : `** 1: syntax error before: '->' **` whenever i am declaring any function for eg. to calculate sum of a list (this is experimental, of cource there is Built In Function for find sum of a list).

```
sum([]) -> 0;
sum([H | T]) -> H + sum(T).
```

in erl shell (v 5.5.5).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't define functions in the shell using the same syntax as in an erl file.

You can define fun's though.

Syntax in the shell needs to be:

```
Sum = fun([], _) -> 0; ([H | T], F) -> H + F(T, F) end,
Sum([1,2,3], Sum).
```

Note that recursive anonymous functions (which this is) are defined in an ugly way.  You basically have to pass the function as an argument to itself.

Comment: aka: want functions in shell? Have fun!

Comment: 10 years later and this is still so difficult to find and understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

The straight answer is that in a module definition file you have attributes, like `-module().`, `-export().` etc, and function definitions, while in the shell you enter expressions to be evaluated. A function definition is not an expression.

If you want to define a local, temporary function in the shell you need to use fun's as @DanielLuna has shown. These are really anonymous unnamed functions so calling themselves recursively is a pain, which is not specific to Erlang but common to all anonymous functions.

N.B.

```
Sum = fun([], _) -> 0; ([H | T], F) -> H + F(T, F) end.
```

in shell does **NOT** define a function called `Sum` but defines an anonymous function and binds the *variable* `Sum` to it.

This is also why the only thing you can do in a module is define functions and not expressions to be evaluated when the module is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I got to the right way of declaring module and exporting functions.

Answer (score 3):

Or use the lists:foldl/2 function. This is copied directly from the Erlang Reference Manual.

```
1> lists:foldl(fun(X, Sum) -> X + Sum end, 0, [1,2,3,4,5]).
15
```