# erlang REPL define range error: cannot execute function

Tags: syntax, erlang, range, read-eval-print-loop

I had this simple text inside erl:

```
$erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
1> right_age(X) when X >= 16, X =< 104 -> true;
1> right_age(_) -> false;
1> right_age(30).
* 1: syntax error before: 'when'
```

Where did I get wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar answer can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612628/erlang-getting-error-1-syntax-error-before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define named functions in the Erlang shell using the approach you show in your question. You must instead use the `fun` keyword to define the function, and bind it to a variable:

```
1> RightAge = fun(X) when X >= 16, X =< 104 -> true; (_) -> false end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.128620087>
2> RightAge(30).
true
```

By the way, note also that you can define this function more easily, with just a single clause, by moving your guard into the function body:

```
1> RightAge = fun(X) -> X >= 16 andalso X =< 104 end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.128620087>
2> RightAge(30).
true
```